# Table without long caption but short caption in list of figures

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, floats, captions

I have a table which I would like not to have a caption (at all), but I would like to be able to insert a short caption so that the table would appear in the list of tables.

How can I do this?

Comment: By "no caption", should it have a number? If not, what exactly should appear in the LoT that identifies the table... just text and a page number?

Comment: Yes please! But only showing the number in the list of tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert a table `desc`ription into the LoT manually using

```
\addcontentsline{lot}{table}{<desc>}
```

Here's an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\begin{table}
  \centering This is a table
  \caption{A table with a caption}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \centering Here is another table without a caption
  \refstepcounter{table}% Increase the table counter
  \addcontentsline{lot}{table}{\protect\numberline{\thetable}A short caption}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The `\addcontentsline` configuration above is similar to what the `\caption` command would do.